# My POP3 sever is sending me both sent and received messages - how to conclusively distinguish

Tags: java, pop3

From a search, I can find a lot of similar questions to this but all of them seem as far as I can tell to have either been misunderstood or to not be quite the same as this question.

Presumably (maybe not but it seem unlikely) an email process/server knows which emails it holds a record of because they "arrived" and which it holds a record of because someone used SMTP or similar to tell the server to "send" an email out.

If a POP3 client retrieves lots of emails from the server and (we know from observation that) some of those emails are emails that the server was told to send out and some are emails it received, then is the pop3 server contravening the protocol because it provided for download, emails which were conceptually NOT in the "Inbox" or is it at liberty to send what ever it wants since POP3 has NO concept of folders and emails are emails.

Either way, is there an easy and robust way for the client to distinguish between these emails?  Or is checking the from field against the account the best on offer?  I believe pop3 messages support flags, some POP3 apis do, but perhaps servers are not obliged to make any guarantees, plus I don't see a very clear description of their meaning, so I don't if they can be consisently used to distinguish.

For implementation my preference is Java and com.sun.mail.pop3

I realize there is IMAP, but at this stage I'd like if possible to make a very small change to POP3 client implementation and look at switching to IMAP another time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

POP3 is a protocol to get the messages of your inbox. To send messages you use SMTP protocol.

In my understanding you contact the server using SMTP and deliver a message to the server. The server then delivers this mail to the corresponding target mail server and stores the message in that inbox. 
On the other side you contact your own inbox using POP3 to receive the message that are stored in your inbox.
Thus there never should be any conflict between ingoing and outgoing emails as these are two different things and the servers supplying pop3 and smtp for your mailbox can be two total different servers on total different locations. Thus, within one mail server inbox and outbox should be two different storage locations.

Comment: Ok.  I have read then that pop3 has no concept of folders and yet it seems it does in a way since it distinguishes between mail in the folder called "inbox" and email not in that folder.  So are you saying that the pop3 server that is sending my pop3 client mail that was sent from the account and is in the sent folder is breaking the pop3 definition?  And that the rest of my question ought not to need to be addressed?  Can it be addressed anyway?

Comment: Also I have seen sent email be moved from a sent folder to an inbox folder, would that mail be legally be offered for download by the pop3 server and if so, again what's the best way to distinguish whether it's an email that was sent from the account or received to the account, just the way I suggest or a better way?

Comment: Outgoing mail go via smtp server and never see the inbox. They may be copied to a certain folder (e.g. sent). You may not send mails using pop3. Pop3 is just for fetching mails from the server

Comment: Re "You may not send mails using pop3. Pop3 is just for fetching mails from the server"  -  I think you are misunderstanding my question.  I am not trying to send emails or ask a mail host to send mail.  I am asking, if the pop3 server serves up to my pop3 client mail that without question mail that was "sent FROM the account", is the pop3 server in some contravention or since it does not recognise folders, can it send what it wants to the client and if it does how does one robustly distinguish between them, just by looking at the from field or some other way.

Comment: Does this make any better sense?  Sorry if the question is not clear, what should I change about my question to make it clearer?

Comment: indeed, it is not very clear. If you ask for a flag or a unique id... there aren't any. You need to check the from field

Answer (score 0):

"Conclusively distinguishing" depends on how/why the messages are being seen in POP3. A best effort type solution, though, would involve substring scanning the From field looking for what was provided in the USER command. If a token based authentication mechanism is being used, then you'll need to get an email identifier from whomever issued the token and look for *that* in From header.

As background, a basic concept in POP3 is called the "maildrop".  Most people equate that to "Inbox" in IMAP terms, but it's not necessarily the same. For example, a message filtered at deposit time into a custom folder *might* show up in POP3's maildrop even though it doesn't show in Inbox via IMAP or Webmail. What goes into the maildrop and is therefore seen in POP3 can vary from implementation to implementation.

If a user only has POP3/SMTP and Webmail as their choices, they'll sometimes BCC themselves on sending to make sure a copy exists *somewhere* on the server so that they can access it via Webmail if needed. That's because very few SMTP implementations automatically save the message to the user's mailbox, and POP3 has no mechanism for saving the message anywhere but local to the user-agent. For those SMTP servers that *do* automatically save sent mail in the mailbox, they might just put it in the maildrop when it comes to POP3 servers.